# Retrieving JSON data in web storage not working

Tags: javascript, json, web-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

I'm trying to store JSON data, name & phonenumber given in two text fields and then later(after page refresh) retrieve and print the data on the same fields with following code.

```
        function saveData() {
            var saveD = { 
                name: document.getElementById("name").value,
                phone: document.getElementById("phone").value
            }; 

            window.localStorage.setItem("info", saveD);
        } 
        var storedData = window.localStorage.getItem("info");

        document.getElementById("name").value = storedData.name;
        document.getElementById("phone").value = storedData.phone;
```

What is wrong? I get "undefined" on both fields.

Comment: You are trying to store an object, not JSON. It will work if you properly convert the object to and from JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!
@Bankzilla, how do I do it?

Comment: click the checkmark next to the answer that is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save like this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem("info", JSON.stringify(saveD));
```

And load like this:

```
var storedData = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("info"));
```

You have to store objects as JSON in local storage.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! I tried to use JSON.stringify before but didn't know about JSON.parse....that's why it wasn't working...

Comment: Thaks! This is what I need and I found it for just 4 seconds :)